# How can I insert my database particular column values into a list in view page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i want to list 'category_name' into a list. i tried but i couldn't.

here is my controller and I'm trying 2 call the fn `get_cat`.
then I'm looking to pass that array to my view page

controller `categorylist`

```
 public function get_categorylist() 
 {
  $data['records']= $this->categorylist_model->get_cat();
  $this->load->view('categorylist_view',$data);  

 }
```

model `Categorylist_model`

```
public function get_cat()
 {

 $this->db->select('category_name');
 $this->db->from('amm_report_category');
 $query = $this->db->get();
       if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
       { 
        return $query->result();
       }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }

    }
```

view `categorylist_view`

```
<body>
<div>
<form action="<? echo base_url(); ?>categorylist/get_categorylist"  method="post">
  <select name="categorylist">
  <? foreach ($result as $var) 
  {?> 
 <option value="<?echo $var->category_name;?>"><?echo $var->category_name;?>       </option>
  <?}?>
  </select>

  <p><input type="submit" value="get_categorylist" name=""/></p>                                         
  </form>
  </div>
  </center>
  </body>
```

Comment: please check the data structure of $result. check print_r($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**model**

```
  public function get_cat()
 {

   $this->db->select('catogory_id,category_name');
   $this->db->from('amm_report_category');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
   { 
    return $query->result();
   }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }

}
```

**view**

```
     <select name="categorylist">
     <? foreach ($records as $var) 
     {?> 
     <option value="<?echo $var->category_id;?>"><?echo $var->category_name;?>       </option>
     <?}?>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

you store data in data['records'] . But you used to display array name as $result.

You need to use in foreach "`foreach ($records as $var)` "

```
      public function get_categorylist() 
         {
          $data['records']= $this->categorylist_model->get_cat();
          $this->load->view('categorylist_view',$data);  

         }
        public function get_cat()
     {


$this->db->select('category_name');

$query = $this->db->get('amm_report_category');
           if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
           { 
            return $query->result();
           }
            else
            {
            return false;
            }

        }     
        <body>
        <div>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>categorylist/get_categorylist"  method="post">
          <select name="categorylist">
          <?php foreach ($records as $var) 
          { ?> 
         <option value="<?php echo $var->category_name;?>"><?php echo $var->category_name; ?>       </option>
          <?php } ?>
          </select>

          <p><input type="submit" value="get_categorylist" name=""/></p>                                         
          </form>
          </div>
          </center>
          </body>
```

Comment: is there any problem in    "       <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>categorylist/get_categorylist"  method="post">"

Comment: Post print_r($records); what it return